# Json jquery(zf2) for populating dependent dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, json, zend-framework2

How will I get json data of 'a' in dropdownlist.The length property is also not showing proper value.For now I am getting blank value in dependent dropdownlist?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("#religioncode").change(function() {
    str=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url:"<?php echo $this->url(NULL,array('controller'=>'Register', 'action' =>'ajax')); ?>",
        data:{
            religioncode:str
        },
        success: function(ajaxresult){
            var appenddata1="";
            $.each(ajaxresult, function (key, value) {
            $("#castecode").append($('<option>  </option>').val(value.castecode).html(value.castename));
        });
        },
            error: function(){
            alert("Failure!!");
        }
    });                     
});
```

});

Comment: There should not be any need to `stringify` as `dataType: 'json',` is already used. And `$.each(ajaxresult....` statement should be inside the `success: function...{ }`.

Comment: Fixed your indentation, which proves that @KunalDethe is correct.

Comment: success: function (data) {
                        var appenddata1 = "";
                         var jsonData1 = JSON.parse(data1.d);
                        for (var i = 0; i < jsonData1.length; i++) {
                            appenddata1 += "<option value = '" + jsonData1[i].castecode + " '>" + jsonData1[i].castename + " </option>";
                        }
                        $("#castecode").append(appenddata1);
                    }
i have done this but still not getting the answer

Comment: Is it working now? Make sure that the result returned is `json_encode(array with key and value)`

Comment: No still not working...

here is my php code in zend controller and it is returning correct array value

foreach ($result as $res) {
       $selectData[] = array('castecode' => $res['castecode'],
      'castename' => $res['castename']); 
            $r = new JsonModel ( array (
            'caste' => $selectData,
    ) );
    return $r;

Comment: Also it should be `.text(...)` instead of `.html(value.castename));`

Comment: No still not working...

here is my php code in zend controller and it is returning correct array value

    foreach ($result as $res) {
       $selectData[] = array('castecode' => $res['castecode'],
      'castename' => $res['castename']); 
            $r = new JsonModel ( array (
            'caste' => $selectData,
        ));
    return $r;

Comment: Before `$.each...` statement, write `ajaxresult = ajaxresult.caste;` - Just to get the idea of the problem here.

Comment: Getting the values in dropdownlist but all values of caste table is being displayed.